# Why does padding-left style result in QComboBox menu stretching to screen height?

Tags: css, qt, padding, qcombobox

Consider the following example. It creates two instances of `QComboBox`: one with a stylesheet, and another without. If the first one is clicked (with widget style being Fusion), the menu is sized as expected, although padding of text is inconsistent between hovered and non-hovered items. But if you click on the second one, the padding problem is now fixed, but the menu appears to have huge entries, making the menu fill the whole screen height.

```
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QComboBox box1, box2;
    const QString stylesheetOrig=R"(
QComboBox::item:selected
{
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
)";
    box1.setStyleSheet(stylesheetOrig);
    box2.setStyleSheet(stylesheetOrig+R"(
QComboBox::item
{
    padding-left: 27px;
}
)");
    box1.addItems({"Hello 1","Goodbye 1"});
    box2.addItems({"Hello 2","Goodbye 2"});
    box1.show();
    box2.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

If I remove the padding statement, still leaving the `QComboBox::item {}` part, then nothing strange (and nothing useful) happens. But if I even set the padding to `1px` or `0px`, the stretching already happens with all its might.

Why does setting *horizontal* padding result in such a strange change vertically?

Comment: What is `QWidget:item` supposed to be? There's no such sub-control on a QWidget (perhaps you're thinking of `QAbstractItemView::item`?) Also controls are usually separated with `::` vs. states which are with one `:`.

Comment: @MaximPaperno Actually it seems to be a typo, there should be `::` there. It's just taken in the same form as the previously existing in the code I'm editing `QWidget:item:selected { background-color: #0000ff; }` (with another color). This lead to currently active item in the combobox having, in addition to background in the menu, a tick mark when hovered, and the text on any hovered item being indented — inconsistently with the unhovered items, to which I was trying to find a remedy. I'm not sure why this even works though if there's no such subcontrol in `QWidget`...

Comment: OK, apparently `QCheckBox::item` does apply to items in the list view even though I don't see it documented anywhere, and overrides any styles set on the item view explicitly (in bizarre ways, even though the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox) say to do exactly that). My guess is `QWidget::item` works because combo box inherits from it... ahh the mysteries of QSS! :)  And I can reproduce the issue with padding -- not sure what's up with that but it sure screws up geometry calculations pretty bad. But post a full example with this icon/tick behavior.

Comment: @MaximPaperno OK, updated and localized the stylesheets to `QComboBox` instead of `QWidget` (with the same behavior).

Comment: I mean post an example of the actual problem with the icon/check mark, or whatever (not sure I understood that part, where does icon come from?). The CSS padding is fairly obviously a bug or some other "anomaly" we could spend [all day](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp.html#_ZN16QStyleSheetStyleC1EP6QStyle) chasing down -- I'd suggest concentrating on a solution to the actual thing you want to solve. Or wait to see if someone has run into this exact issue before.

Comment: @MaximPaperno this updated example already demonstrates the problem in `box1`. The checkmark comes somewhere from Qt itself, when I add `stylesheetOrig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow OK, that is screwy indeed. Adding any css to a combo box makes it go into some other "retro" mode with showing icons next to the current item. I've never noticed that in many years, but I see a bunch of common threads on the issue. Seems to only affect Fusion style though, I was confused for a while on my Windows box until I figured that out.

The question is if you want the checkbox or not. Here's one way to get rid of it, the only consistent one I found after a bit of playing with it. The main trick is setting the selection colors on the `::item` and not on `::item:selected` (the latter makes the checkmarks appear).

```css
QComboBox::item { 
  selection-background-color: #0000ff;
  selection-color: palette(highlighted-text);
}
```

[image]

PS. Another reason for confusion and why `QComboBox::item` and `:checked` even work is that the QComboBox default item delegate (used to draw the items in the QListView which the combo box uses for the options list) "pretends" it's a `QMenu`: [QComboMenuDelegate::paint()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qcombobox_p.h.html#_ZNK18QComboMenuDelegate5paintEP8QPainterRK20QStyleOptionViewItemRK11QModelIndex)
So another workaround would be to use something more sane/customizable for a delegate, perhaps even a default `QStyledItemDelegate`.

---

*ADDED*: A version keeping the checkbox and ensuring the unchecked items have padding (w/out using `padding` property which appears to be FUBAR when used in a combo box item with Fusion style). The icon size seems easiest set via `iconSize` property -- I tried a few ways via css icon/image/element width/height but nothing affected it... probably because the `iconSize` property overrides it.

```css
QComboBox { qproperty-iconSize: 12px; }       /* or QComboBox::setIconSize() */
QComboBox::indicator { color: transparent; }  /* to force space for the icon column */

/* Using ::item:selected vs. ::item { selection-*-color: } will apparently make the 
  checkbox column appear... at least with Fusion as the main style */
QComboBox::item:selected { 
  color: palette(highlighted-text); 
  background-color: #0000ff; 
}
```

[image]

---

*VERSION 3* (as per comments):

```css
QComboBox { qproperty-iconSize: 12px; }       /* or QComboBox::setIconSize() */
QComboBox::indicator:!checked { border: 0; }  /* to force space for the icon column */
QComboBox::item { background-color: palette(base); }  /* gets rid of icon|text separator */

/* Using ::item:selected vs. ::item { selection-*-color: } will apparently make the 
  checkbox column appear... at least with Fusion as the main style */
QComboBox::item:selected { 
  color: palette(highlighted-text); 
  background-color: #0000ff; 
}
```

[image]

There's still a 1px frame line at the top of the unselected icon area, though it's pretty subtle. I have no idea where that comes from... tried some guesses but to no avail.

Comment: I actually do find the icon useful. Is there a way to preserve it, but adjust the text padding to be 1) consistent and 2) smaller than it is otherwise?

Comment: @Ruslan Added example of that also.  I say, QComboBox must be one of the most confusing (and perhaps worst documented) widgets to style -- it's basically just trial and error to see what works (eg. some of the QMenu styling works, but not nearly all of it... though then again the QMenu styling docs are pretty vague also, and it also sucks to style menus).

Comment: This is almost ideal... but how to get rid of this newly-appeared frame around the empty space for the checkmark? It doesn't seem to be an "empty box" taking place of the checkmark, but rather some kind of border/frame...

Comment: @Ruslan Here you go... not pixel-perfect but ok.  You could probably go further if you provide your own checkmark icon, or style the indicator yourself entirely (a sunken frame or whatever... there's an example in the QSS Examples for [QMenu](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu)).